# Mimic PHP's ksort in C#

Tags: c#, php, linq, ksort

I never thought I would have to ask this... I need a way to mimic PHP's `ksort` function in C#.

Here's the problem... PHP does this...

**PHP CODE**

```
$arr = array(
    "tagValues" => "asdfasd",
    "email" => "asdfasd",
    "referrer" => "asdfasd",
    "tags" => "asdfasd",
);

echo "Base array \n\n";
print_r($arr);

ksort($arr);

echo "\n\nksort'ed array \n\n";
print_r($arr);
```

**PHP OUTPUT**

```
Base array 

Array
(
    [tagValues] => asdfasd
    [email] => asdfasd
    [referrer] => asdfasd
    [tags] => asdfasd
)


ksort'ed array 

Array
(
    [email] => asdfasd
    [referrer] => asdfasd
    [tagValues] => asdfasd
    [tags] => asdfasd
)
```

While if I do this in C#...

```
string[] sortedKeys = form.AllKeys.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

It comes out in a different order. `tags` will be before `tagValues`, as it rightfully should be. That is the true alphabetically order.

It's my understanding that `ksort` does some kind of case-sensitive ASCII work on the array and that's why it comes out in a different order.

***How can I implement that in C#?*** Preferably with LINQ. Thanks!

*For those interest in the backstory...*

I'm basically trying to create an MD5 hash of input parameters sorted in alpha order per the [FastSpring](http://www.fastspring.com/) API. Their PHP snippet operates differently than I expected when I translated to C#, so the hash is always incorrect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keyword is [*StringComparer.Ordinal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal.aspx)

```
string[] sortedKeys= form.AllKeys.OrderBy(x => x,StringComparer.Ordinal).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your gravatar made me thinking there is a layout issue on SO